# Передача аргументов командной строки в приложение

Tags: c#

В коде программы объявить параметры командной строки так, чтобы когда подгружаем компилятор C#, в командной строке мы ввели имя входного файла и выходного файла и наша программа отработала.

**Добавлено.**

Пример: есть программа по инверсии байт. Мы вызываем cmd, пишем название программы, имя входного и выходного файла, и смотрим выходной файл.

Comment: Больше восклицательных знаков и она обязательно отработает! А по существу, что нужно то?

Comment: Корректнее опишите суть проблемы.

Comment: Вам нужно в программе на C# взять имя файла из параметра запуска компилятора, который компилит эту программу ?

Comment: Пример: есть программа по инверсии байт. Мы вызываем cmd, пишем название программы, имя входного и выходного файла, и смотрим выходной файл.

Comment: это нужно сделать на С#///

Comment: Вроде эта штука argv или arg называется

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вы запускаете программу как `ConsoleApplication file1.txt file2.txt`, то параметры можете получить через [аргументы Main()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cb20e19t.aspx):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            string file1 = args[0];
            string file2 = args[1];
            ..
        }    
    }
```

Или можно обратиться к массиву [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) (здесь нолевой элемент - имя программы):

```
string file1 = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];
```