# Обработка аргументов командной строки в c#

Tags: c#

Как происходит обработка аргументов командной строки?

Comment: [Вот так?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/acy3edy3.aspx)

Comment: @Alekcvp нет ю//

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/30241/198316 тут хороший ответ по сути, но вопрос оформлен плохо. Дубль?

Comment: @ATOM, так она происходит, так. Или переформулируйте вопрос.